# Odour from Tenant after it rains

Tags: rain, barometric-pressure, air-quality

I own a furniture business which is located next to a dog daycare.  When it rains the stench of the dog daycare appears in my space.  We recognize the smell as it is identical to what you smell when you enter the dog daycare.

Can you explain why the stench appears after it rains?  We had an air duct and HVAC expert visit the dog daycare and they both agreed that it may be due to a lack of ventilation in the dog daycare.

I am trying to, from a scientific perspective, explain what occurs when it rains i.e. high versus low pressure, moisture, etc. to my landlord and the gal that has the dog daycare.

Much appreciate your assistance.

Comment: In case you don't get an answer here try on SE Engineering. Someone who is knowledgeable about HVAC or ventilation might be able to help. HVAC & ventilation engineers tend to know more about atmospheric conditions than HVAC technicians. The solution may just be the dog center installing a vent fan exhausting high up or away from the building & in a direction where the prevailing wind won't blow the dog exhaust air.towards the building. As to why it's happening I'd be leaning towards still air, no wind, & atmospheric moisture absorbing odors; maybe even an atmospheric temperature inversion.

Comment: Sounds like a form of [*pet*richor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrichor).  I'm only half joking here - the outdoor spaces likely have doggy molecules that could be  aerosolized by the rain.  Also rain tends to be associated with an up-tick in wind speed, which will act as ventilation for all those built-up indoor doggy scents.

Comment: I would think the first key question would be... is it coming in through openings/doors, or through the AC.  And if the AC, where are the air intakes?  Does it smell everywhere in the store the same/at the same time, or is it worse in some areas?  Should help narrow that down at least.